# UK Visa Sponsorship not in written offer

Tags: professionalism, job-offer, visa

After a long wait, I received an offer from a UK company.
From the first contact until the latest, everyone was (still is) aware that as an EU, I will require a VISA sponsorship, and they even offered me a relocation package (verbally)

The company's recruiter informed me that I would receive the sponsorship certificate after accepting the offer. I thought this was logical.

But what worries me is that the written offer doesn't mention the certificate of sponsorship or the relocation package.

Should I ask the recruiter to include the visa sponsorship in the written offer? Or is this something that is not included in offers?

Comment: Call them and ask for clarification. Don't leave something as important as this to chance, guesswork or unknown people on the internet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Should I ask the recruiter to include the visa sponsorship in the written offer?

Yes. Call them or write them ASAP. Anything officially included in a written offer is much better than if it shows up only on a verbal offer.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, ask them, but be sure to ask in writing.

You want this stuff written down and you want their answer to be written down as well. This includes any offer of a relocation package or visa sponsorship.

Also, you need to know what's the plan if your visa (or travel plan) gets denied, or gets delayed, through no fault of your own.

Have you seen the final contract and the employee handbook? Will you be expected to front the money for the relocation (even if they reimburse you for most of it)? Will you be paid the same amount and get the same benefits even if you're forced to work from your home country and work remotely? Do not give a firm answer until you've read everything.

If you accept their offer too quickly, then yes, they'll start the visa process with an immigration lawyer, which is good, but HR will also place your file at the bottom of their pile and it will be harder to get some of those uncertainties addressed, should there be delays.